# I need a variable that have a small range value

Tags: c

I have an input number that it's value is not always consistent, i mean the value change plus 1 or minus 1 and etc. So, i want to compare it with a const but have a small range value, for example a const int Dist that have value between 14 to 16. Is that possible to implement it on C programming? Please help me.

Comment: No, there is no such variable type in C. But you can certainly implement conditional logic to perform such a check. Just write a function that checks that the input is within the required range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set constant for lower bound, and constant for upper bound and check if the value falls within the range.

Pseudocode:

```
int const LOWER_BOUND = 14;
int const UPPER_BOUND = 16;

if (input <= UPPER_BOUND && input >= LOWER_BOUND)
    ... logic here ...
```